# DirectX10 Skydomes

Tags: graphics, directx, 3d, directx-10

I'm currently trying to implement a skydome in DirectX10 but I am having real problems trying to find a good tutorial online as to how I go about this. I even looked through all four pages of results I got from looking for "DirectX10 skydomes" in the search function.

Does anyone here know of any good site/books/tutorials etc that can help me in the production of creating a semi-decent looking skydome?

Comment: Skyboxes are better in most cases, is there a reason you require a dome?

Comment: I don't know how to do either in DirectX10. All I know is domes are a bit easier as you don't need to worry about textures lining up etc as you do with boxes.

I'm open to finding ways to do both.

Answer (score 2):

SDKs for DirectX, Ogre3D and possibly also Scenix include demos with Sky-boxes and Sky-domes. Conceptually they're all very simple (use a large inward facing hemisphere or box and move the model with the camera (eye) position so that you never move relative to it). A quick Google yielded a tutorial in the Ogre3D wiki that goes into more detail about the concept http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Basic+Tutorial+3#Sky
Basically the steps are: 1. Create a large hemisphere model (flip the normals to have it face inwards). 2. Map a "fish-eye" sky texture to it 3. Load and render it in DirectX with a non-lit shader (so that no shading is applied... just the sky texture).

Comment: A very important part not mentioned in the answer is to disable depth testing (or writing) while rendering the sky. You need it both showing up behind all other geometry (as it is infinitely far away, this is solved by rendering it first) and not preventing other geometry from being drawn (disable writing to depth).

Answer (score 2):

Quite a bit of detail on how to do this in DX10 & 11 here:
http://www.braynzarsoft.net/index.php?p=SkyMap